# linker error in numerical recipe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, numerical-recipes

My situation is I have a one file c++ code and it uses numerical recipe library.

I have included all numerical recipe files in "Additional Include Directories"
nr.h
nrexit.cpp
nrtypes.h
nrtypes_lib.h
nrtypes_nr.h 
nrutil.h
nrutil_mtl.h 
nrutil_nr.h
nrutil_tnt.h 
nrutil_val.h 
print_array.h

But, when I build, I am getting the following error.

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   NR::splint(class NRVec const &,class NRVec const
>   &,class NRVec const &,double,double &)"
>   (?splint@NR@@YAXABV?$NRVec@N@@00NAAN@Z) referenced in function "void
>   __cdecl smooth_disp_Line(double *,int *,int,int,double *,double *,int,int)" (?smooth_disp_Line@@YAXPANPAHHH00HH@Z)
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   NR::spline(class NRVec const &,class NRVec const
>   &,double,double,class NRVec &)"
>   (?spline@NR@@YAXABV?$NRVec@N@@0NNAAV2@@Z) referenced in function "void
>   __cdecl smooth_disp_Line(double *,int *,int,int,double *,double *,int,int)" (?smooth_disp_Line@@YAXPANPAHHH00HH@Z)

This error is coming from the existing code. So, can somebody tell me about the error ?

Comment: You're either missing building with a source/object file, missing a library, or you simply haven't implemented those functions.

Comment: @asit_dhal, use NR3 not NR2.